# How do I keep the URL in the address bar when stopping page load in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Suppose I am visiting a page in Firefox and decide to go somewhere else and type the new URL manually into the address field, but the page fails to load, either because it times out, or because I hit Escape. Then Firefox *removes my* laboriously entered *URL* and *replaces it* with the URL of the current page.

**This is outrageous!**

I am pretty sure Firefox has changed this behavior lately, because this was one of the reasons I chose Firefox over IE back in the day.

How can I turn off this annoying behavior?

OS: Windows 7
Firefox version: 22 (**update**: still present in 34.0.5)

Answer (score 1):

You might be hitting https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858448
I have reproduced your issue with a clean install of windows 7 and firefox 22 and I confirm it.
I suggest voting for the bug and pursuing mozilla development team to change it's resolution from "UNCONFIRMED" to "NEW"

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, because that bug talks about tabs opened from links with target="_blank", but I get this behavior with tabs I opened with the "New tab" command in Firefox and visit another page before trying the slow page.

Comment: But if it's the same behaviour then it should be same root cause, wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, only the devs know. The description in that bug is more narrow than my use case, I think...

Answer (score -3):

Instead of address bar use the search bar or start use [bookmarks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/create-bookmarks-save-your-favorite-webpages) already.

With [Google "I'm Feeling Lucky"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#.22I.27m_Feeling_Lucky.22) you don't will see difference between address bar and search bar(except search engines keywords). But then you will search in internet with address bar and use search bar like you used address bar previously(except normal search).

---

**Update:**

Open notepad paste this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>fake address bar by potato</title>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="go(); return false">
<input type="text" id="fake_address_bar" size="100" autofocus>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function go() {
window.location='http://'+document.getElementById('fake_address_bar').value;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Save with `fake_address_bar.html` filename. Drag and drop this file to browser and bookmark it.
Now you have own address bar with built-in history.

Comment: If need more info i can add, but much later. crazypotato.jpg

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question at all. I'm looking for some way to configure Firefox to stop removing what I have typed.

Comment: @Peter Jaric Did you even try search bar? Esc don't remove what you typed. If page failed its also can't be removed. So this answer your question. Ok if you don't understand type `superuser.com` in search bar(try press Esc). What you will see on 1st place in google search? With feeling lucky you can skip this page and go directly to `superuser.com`. So search bar will act like address bar. Or in search results you can press arrow down on keyboard and hit enter and you will be on `superuser.com`. And again start use bookmarks. srsly

Comment: 1) I don't want to send all my urls to Google. 2) Google do not index all kinds of URLs. 3) Google do not index servers it can not see (on private networks). 4) Who would like to bookmark every URL before going to it? (OK, I know you don't mean that, but (web) developers like me try many different new URLs all the time)